# How do I calculate the exponent in a for loop in python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate the exponent of the numbers

```
print("Start")
for i in [3,4,5]
  print("Hola, ahora i vale"+str(i) + "y su exponent" + i ** 2 )
print("End")
```

TypeError: must be str, not int

Answer (score 4):

You must cast the `int` to `str` before printing:

```
print("Start")
for i in [3,4,5]:
    print("Hola, ahora i vale" + str(i) + "y su exponent" + str(i ** 2) )
print("End")
```

Or you could do like this, using the `format` syntax:

```
print("Start")
for i in [3,4,5]:
    print("Hola, ahora i vale {} y su exponent {}".format(i, i ** 2))
print("End")
```

Comment: If you are answering this, you should really talk about how to do proper string formatting in Python.

Comment: Thanks @ReblochonMasque

Comment: Glad I could help; I added an example using the `format` syntax for printing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert `i ** 2` to a string just like you converted `i`.

```
print("Hola, ahora i vale"+str(i) + "y su exponent" + str(i ** 2))
```

Alternatively you can let `print()` handle it by passing it as an argument:

```
print("Hola, ahora i vale", i, "y su exponent", i ** 2)
```

Another option is using string formatting:

```
print("Hola, ahora i vale%dy su exponent%d" % (i, i ** 2))
```

With Python 3.6, you can also do:

```
print(f"Hola, ahora i vale{i}y su exponent{i ** 2}")
```

See https://pyformat.info/ for a few more options.

Answer (score 0):

Python is strongly typed, and doesn't do automatic coercing. You need to do an explicit cast of the result of the exponentiation to concatenate it with a string:

```
... + "y su exponent" + str(i ** 2) )
```

Comment: please, talk about string formatting, and how this is done in Python, not just "+" to concatenate strings.

Comment: @jsbueno That is perhaps the dumbest reason I've ever been downvoted for. Proper string formatting is entirely besides the question. Maybe as an extra it would be appropriate.

Comment: The OP is trying to learn Python. This question has probably been asked, and answered, a thousand times before in S.O. alone. You decide: you want t teach proper Python, or just give out a "quick, correct answer to grab some points"? BTW, I like the site points myself, and that is one of the reasons I simply don't close questions like this by finding the first suitable duplicate everytime. The other reason not to close is a sort of "you are welcome" to new users, that would otherwise be turned away from the place.